# R Automate the execution of a script on Linux

Tags: r, centos, scheduled-tasks

I would like to run an R script on a Linux server (CentOS) in an automated way. This should be done once a day (if possible several times a day). I would like to download stock prices using R (and later enter them into a database).
For example, the R script looks like this:

```
library(tidyquant)
library(lubridate)

data<-tq_get("AAPL", from="2021-01-01", to=today())
```

How should I write a job so that I can run the script automatically within a certain interval?
Can anyone help me?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at scheduling packages, such as https://rdrr.io/cran/cronR/ ?

Comment: You may simply use Linux' [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) command, to run either an R script (executable with shebang), or a bash script that will call R. I have currently several scripts running with cron, at different frequencies (hourly, dayly) to analyse Covid data.

Comment: @jared_mamrot, Yes, in the meantime, I have also found this package. Does it also work if I have closed RStudio?

Answer (score 1):

you might would like to create a service. Depends on the CentOS version what type of service [Systemd or init deamon](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/centos/169/systemd-custom-service.html)

- Full information of a timed service and the workings [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-schedule-tasks-with-systemd-timers-in-linux).
- Simple tutorial of how to create services [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-write-a-simple-systemd-service)

This lets you create a service with the desired conditions and run your application/script.

Service example:

services are located @ `/etc/systemd/system/`

for example open cli `sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/updatestockdb.service`
go into file and write your service `sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/updatestockdb.service`

```
[unit]
Description=Update stock price DB
Type=simple

[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily
AccuracySec=12h
Persistent=true

ExecStart=/opt/scripts/fetch_Stonks.sh --full --to-external
Restart=on-failure
PIDFile=/tmp/yourservice.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```